# RepositoryItemReader - How can I use a method with List parameter

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following repository:

```
@Repository
public interface InterlocutorRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Interlocutor, UsuarioId> {
    Page<Interlocutor> findByFlCadastroOnlineIn(List<StatusCadOnline> flCadastroOnline, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And I have the following reader in my Spring Batch App:

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<Interlocutor> reader() {
        List<StatusCadOnline> listaStatusCadOnline = new ArrayList();
        listaStatusCadOnline.add(StatusCadOnline.PENDENTE);
        listaStatusCadOnline.add(StatusCadOnline.ERRO);

        RepositoryItemReader<Interlocutor> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.setRepository(repository);
        reader.setMethodName("findByFlCadastroOnlineIn");
        reader.setArguments(listaStatusCadOnline);

        HashMap<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
        sorts.put("nrCpf", Sort.Direction.ASC);
        reader.setSort(sorts);

        return reader;
    }
```

Spring Batch is understanding that my method has two arguments of type StatusCadOnline instead of a single parameter of type List.

LogError:

```
ERROR [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-178] b.c.a.c.b.steps.ItemSkipPolicy.shouldSkip 12 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.findByFlCadastroOnlineIn(br.com.alelo.corp.core.model.enumerator.StatusCadOnline, br.com.alelo.corp.core.model.enumerator.StatusCadOnline, org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest)
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the JPA's **findBy*In()** with **RepositoryItemReader**:

You'll need to receive a list of arguments, and to do that you have to change your attributes to a List<List<?>>

Example of running code solution to your case:

```
...
List<List<StatusCadOnline>> arguments = new ArrayList();
List<StatusCadOnline> attributeListIn = new ArrayList();
attributeListIn.add(StatusCadOnline.PENDENTE);
attributeListIn.add(StatusCadOnline.ERRO);
arguments.add(attributeListIn);

RepositoryItemReader<Filial> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
reader.setRepository(branchRepository);
reader.setMethodName("findByFlCadastroOnlineIn");
reader.setArguments(arguments);
...
```

Comment: Thiago,
I tried your solution and it works.
Thanks a lot.